# How to add vertical space inside a \framebox

Tags: vertical-spacing, box, vspace, add-vertical-space

Consider the MWE below. I would like to add some vertical space above the blue square, *inside* the `framebox` (indicated by red arrow).

Why is `\vspace` ignored? Which command should I use?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
\centerline{\framebox{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[blue] (0,0) |- (1,2) |- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
}}
\caption{Rectangle}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[t]
\centerline{\framebox{
\vspace{2cm} %Why ignored?
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[blue] (0,0) |- (1,1) |- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
}}
\caption{Square}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why `\vspace` is ignored; `\vspace*`, which preserves space at the top of a page is ignored as well.

But inserting the equivalent of a strut at the top of the box will leave the white space you are looking for:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\framebox{
%\vspace{2cm} %Why ignored?                                                     
\vrule height 2cm width 0pt
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[blue] (0,0) |- (1,1) |- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{Square}                                                                        
\end{figure}
```

[image: output of code example]

Comment: you can't have a vskip in an hbox

Answer (score 1):

`\framebox` typesets its contents in (restricted) horizontal mode, so vertical space is ignored completely.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox{\higherfboxsave}
\newlength{\higherfboxlen}
\newcommand{\higherfbox}[2]{% #1 = additional height, #2 = material to box
  \sbox{\higherfboxsave}{#2}%
  \setlength{\higherfboxlen}{\ht\higherfboxsave}%
  \addtolength{\higherfboxlen}{#1}%
  \fbox{\rule{0pt}{\higherfboxlen}\usebox{\higherfboxsave}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\fbox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \filldraw[blue] (0,0) |- (1,2) |- cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\caption{Rectangle}

\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\higherfbox{1cm}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \filldraw[blue] (0,0) |- (1,1) |- cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\caption{Square}

\end{figure}

\lipsum[2][1-3]

\end{document}
```

Avoid the foreign command `\centerline` and also be careful with added spaces (check for `%` in the code above).

[image]